# r1c1 formula not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rank values using column J and tie breaker in column K with the result populating in column N. Column J & K are values.

Somehow it only generates one value wherever my cell is pointed at, which means if I run the vba codes at cell C19, it will just populate value 1 in C19, not from N6 where I want the results to be.

Here are my codes,

```
Sub test()
Dim LR1 As Long
LR1 = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("N6:N" & LR1)
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=1+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C10:R33C10<RC[-4]))+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C11:R33C11<RC[-3]),--(R6C10:R33C10=RC[-4]))"
End With
End Sub
```

I am not sure what went wrong. I tried to do it manually using the excel formula and its working fine but not my vba codes.

Comment: Never *needed* to use R1C1 referencing in 15 years of Excel/VBA. What's wrong with A1?

Comment: if my excel pointer is at A1 it will just populate value 1 in A1 and nothing else is been calculated.

Comment: if there is a faster method, please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveCell` is your issue.

Change
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=1+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C10:R33C10<RC[-4]))+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C11:R33C11<RC[-3]),--(R6C10:R33C10=RC[-4]))"`

To `.FormulaR1C1 = "=1+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C10:R33C10<RC[-4]))+SUMPRODUCT(--(R6C11:R33C11<RC[-3]),--(R6C10:R33C10=RC[-4]))"`

Remove that and it should do what you want.

You will want to fully qualify your `Range` references that way they aren't depending on the `ActiveSheet`. This will provide you with consistent behavior and results.